# System.Data.SqlClient in Visual Studio Code on Debian 9.9

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, sqlclient

I've installed Visual Studio Code on Debian 9.9 with .Net Core 2.0. Using the mssql package, I've been able to query a SQL Server database running in Docker on the same machine. However, when I try to use System.Data.SqlClient to query the database in a C# console application, I keep getting errors saying that SqlConnection and SqlCommand are deprecated and that I need to use System.Data.SqlClient version 0.0.0.0. I can't find that version (I was pretty sure it didn't exist when I saw the message), so I'm wondering if maybe there's some kind of weird configuration thing that I don't know. If anyone else has had this issue and figured out a solution, would you mind sharing how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obviously an old question, but in case someone else stumbles upon it:

You need to add the package to your project. You can do this in VS Code by using the terminal, and entering the command `dotnet add package System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: Hey, sorry for taking so long. I usually forget to log in to SO when I'm looking for answers, so didn't know this had gotten a reply. Thanks for the help!